# Nifti file, what does it look like

Tags: nifti

I have two nifti files, when I open them in a notepad, one has a lot of euro-signs in it, while the other one has just lines and lines of nothing. Can the one with the signs in be a 'wrong' file?

Update: I opened them both in HEX viewer, and it seems that every empty space in the later is replaced by a euro sign in the first document.

Comment: This format is binary and is not appropriate for viewing with a text editor/viewer. You might want to look up the format specification document and open the files with HEX viewer to see if these are per the specification.

Comment: So you're saying that the one with a lot of euro signs is in binary format, and the other one would be in hexadecimal? So I should be able to convert them?

Comment: No, I am not saying that. I am saying that this file format is a binary format (as opposed to text format) and you cannot draw any conclusions about them based on what you are seeing in notepad.

Comment: Mmhh, I have a bunch of other files whith the empty space, and they all work with an application I'm using, the other one doesn't. So I figured that there was a difference in both, and the euro signs were the only thing I coud find... I will take a look at it in HEX viewer like you recommended